# CSS transitions on ajax images

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, css-transitions

So im trying to build a css slider using fadein/fadeout transitions with images loaded with ajax. the problem is that when the ajax images come and the css transition effect of fade should work, it doesnt. But the transitions works well after the images are loaded the first time(since i am checking if the images exist).

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luismatute/wRqrs/1/) as an example

here is the code:

```
<style>
    body{ margin:0px; }
    #wrapper{
        position:relative;
        width:1024px;
        height:768px;
    }
    #wrapper img{
        position:absolute;
        width:;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
         -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
           -o-transition: all 0.5s;
              transition: all 0.5s;
    }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <img class="selected" src="img/photo01.jpg" />
</div>
<script>
    var images = [
            {image:'img/photo01.jpg', loaded:true},
            {image:'img/photo02.jpg', loaded:false},
            {image:'img/photo03.jpg', loaded:false},
            {image:'img/photo04.jpg', loaded:false},
            {image:'img/photo05.jpg', loaded:false}
        ],
        arrIndex = 0,
        zIndex = 1,
        timer = 1500,
        fadeInTime = 500,
        timerID,
        isLoading = false,
        container,
        imgPrefix = 'slideImage_',
        curSelected = $('#'+imgPrefix+arrIndex);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        container = $('#wrapper');
        timerID = setTimeout(nextImage,timer);
        $('img',container).attr('id',imgPrefix + arrIndex);
    });

    function nextImage(){
        if(!isLoading){
            arrIndex++;
            arrIndex = arrIndex >= images.length ? 0 : arrIndex;
            loadImage();
        }
    }

    function prevImage(){
        if(!isLoading){
            arrIndex--;
            arrIndex = arrIndex < 0 ? images.length-1 : arrIndex;
            loadImage();
        }
    }

    function loadImage(){
        var imgObj = images[arrIndex];

        isLoading = true;
        zIndex++;
        $('img:visible').css('opacity',0);

        if(imgObj.loaded){
            // $('#'+imgPrefix + arrIndex).hide().css('z-index',zIndex).fadeIn(fadeInTime);
            $('#'+imgPrefix + arrIndex).css({'opacity': 1})
            setTimer();
        } else {
            $('<img />')
            .load(function(){
                // $(this).hide();
                container.append(this);
                //$(this).fadeIn(fadeInTime);
                imgObj.loaded = true;
                setTimer();
            })
            .attr('id', imgPrefix + arrIndex)
            .attr('src',imgObj.image)
            .css({'opacity': 1});;
        }
    }

    function setTimer(){
        isLoading = false;
        timerID = setTimeout(nextImage,timer);
    }

</script>
```

Hope you understand

Comment: call me crazy, but you're already bringing in these images with AJAX and jquery ... why not make it `$('#'+imgPrefix + arrIndex).css({'opacity': 1},500)` and `$('img:visible').css({opacity:0},500);`? i normally advocate CSS solutions, but since you're already using jQuery ...

Comment: i want it to look smooth on an ipad or mobile, and jquery does that kinda slow

Comment: well the problem is you're just switching out the img and reloading them ... the DOM sees this as the same picture, and the transitions have already been applied to that picture.

Comment: i dont think so, because im checking if they exists first, if they dont exists, then i add them by ajax. the problem occurs only the first time they are loaded, then it works how it is supposed to

Comment: if u want, there is an alternative. i wrote a blog about CSS-only slideshows a while back on my old design site, and u would only need jQuery for IE9-. that way u can do fadeIn/fadeOut in jQuery for internet exploder, but for mobile / W3C browsers u could use pure CSS. just offering => http://lifeinthegrey.com/blog.php?id=13

Comment: thats a good example, i ve done some css sliders before. my problem thou, is that i need to load the images with ajax. thanks anyway ;)